# Attached events in WPF: an OK button always requires 2 clicks to close

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleAttahEvent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel  Margin="5"  Name="stackButton" ButtonBase.Click="DoSomething">
            <Button Name="cmd1" Tag="The first button"> Command 1</Button>
            <Button Name="cmd2" Tag="The second button"> Command 2</Button>
            <Button Name="cmd3" Tag="The third button"> Command 3</Button>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...With the following code to handle the attached events.

```
namespace SimpleAttahEvent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stackButton.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(DoSomething));
        }

        private void DoSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Button.ClickEvent.RoutingStrategy);
            Console.WriteLine(TextBox.PreviewKeyDownEvent.RoutingStrategy);
            if (e.Source == cmd1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("First button is clicked");
            }
            if (e.Source == cmd2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Second button is clicked");
            }
            if (e.Source == cmd3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Third button is clicked");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

These produce a dialog box with 3 buttons stacked vertically. When I click one of the button, a messagebox comes up with an OK button. However, the OK button on the dialogue box won't close unless I clicked it twice. Did I do this implicitly from the code given above?

***Edit - Additional Info:***

When I do this instead

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object tag = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag;
            MessageBox.Show((string)tag);

        }
```

..it still require 2 clicks to close the message box.

Comment: This works for me. Is there any other code that might be interacting with this functionality?

Comment: These are all that I have. I couldn't think of anything else that would interact with this functionality.

Comment: How about try it without the routed event handler?  Just define Click handlers in each button as a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doubling your handler. You do not have to click twice on the same `OK`; you are clicking on OK, which closes the first message. Then, the event is handled again and you get another exact same message that you have to click OK on.  If you add `+ DateTime.Now` to your messages you will see that this is indeed a second message

I missed this line on my first glance:

```
stackButton.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(DoSomething));
```

Which is the same as the `ButtonBase.Click` from this line

```
<StackPanel  Margin="5"  Name="stackButton" ButtonBase.Click="DoSomething">
```

Choose one way to attach to event handlers and stick to it. Mixing them up is just going to cause confusion.